# jMapping V2.0 : not drawing markers in Rails 3 + jQuery-UJS project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, heroku

i got a problem using jMapping V2.0 in a rails 3 project, it doesn't show up the markers, the plugin uses MarkerManager v3 1.0 to manage the markers, i tested with mozilla and chrome and both doesn't show the markers.. the web page is http://inmoble.heroku.com/mapa so you could take a look at the code, please if someone could point me in the right direction, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving your included google javascript files to the start of your javascript list of files.

You have:

```
<script src="/javascripts/map/StyledMarker.js?1291880427" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/map/markermanager.js?1291880427" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.3&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Change to:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.3&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/map/StyledMarker.js?1291880427" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/map/markermanager.js?1291880427" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: works like charm :).. thanks Mcloving.. btw this is my first question.. how could i raise your reputation? thanks once again :)

Comment: No problem landox. You just select the big '0' to the left beside my answer I think, should say 'Accept this as answer'. I think thats how anyway, you are my first acceptance too :)